# Javascript tooltip performance

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a list of entries, for each entry I have to create a tooltip in javascript, what do you think is better to do considering the performance?

1) create a div for the popup and another hidden div for each entry that contains the content of the popup, and each time a tooltip is created copy the content of the corresponding div into the one for the popup and display it.

2) create a div for each entry, when it have to display the tooltip do an Ajax call to retrieve the content of the popup and put into the div (if it isn't done before) and display the tooltip

EDIT:
the tooltip should display a complex HTML, the clients could be mobile or computer the list is small because is paginated

Comment: It's quite hard to answer this question. How many list items do you have? If you have a *small* number, 1. If you have lots (100's+), probably 2. This boils down to the size of the HTML page you download when loading the page, and the time it takes to download that content. You need to see when you perceive the request takes too long. What are your clients connected via? Mobile users will feel the bigger transfer more than others. How slow is your server? Will the users be clicking one or many? If they're clicking every one, #1 becomes more favourable (maybe).

Comment: If the content inside your tooltip does not need any HTML/CSS formatting, using the HTML title attribute on the div(s) you want tooltip for is by far the fastest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice strongly depends on how many elements and how much content is stored inside the tooltip.

An ajax call is expensive if you think people will tends to open tooltips many times, but if they may contain images, videos, facebook likes, tons of text and/or other expensive resources it could be a good idea with some kind of cache strategy so you have no more than one ajax call for every tooltip (e.g using the `localstorage` on modern browser)

if tooltips contain instead no more than a couple of paragraphs is quite useless to add complexity to your application with ajax calls, server-side security issues and extra javascript. Just insert them statically

Comment: I had to recently code tooltips with google maps inside, so it came natural think about it

Comment: the tooltip should display a "complex" HTML(it isn't rich of images but at least a simple text), the clients could be also mobile and the list is small because is paginated

Comment: on a mobile device even a request could be expensive (you've no clue about offline/online state and speed connection)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually create a JavaSrript array or object with all of the loaded tooltip values and then replace the text in the tooltip DIV when showing it. Creating a bunch of DIVs will not help performance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a jQuery plugin such as [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) or [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

Comment: Dojo has a tooltip by the looks of things: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tooltip.html